# Can I call route internally?

Tags: ruby, cron, sinatra

I use only one file for sinatra application (*sinatra.rb*) where I have a route:

```
get '/ajax2?' do
  my_function()
end
```

Can I call `my_function()` from *another ruby script* (cron.rb) and *passing all the params*? So whatever code is in this route is executed the same way if I accessed it from a browser?

I need to call it from a cron job.

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
- sinatra (1.3.2)
- sinatra-advanced-routes (0.5.1)
- sinatra-reloader (0.5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**:

pretty sure all you need is a module, like so, in **my_module.rb**:

```
module MyModule
  def my_function
  end
end
```

then in your **app.rb**:

```
require './my_module.rb'
helpers MyModule
```

you you can require and include that module in your cron.rb

---

If I follow your question correctly (not sure I do), pull your code out into an extension, so your directory structure looks like this:

```
myapp/
|-lib/
  |-my_extension.rb
|-app.rb
```

then in **my_extension.rb**:

```
module Sinatra
  module MyExtension
    def self.registered(app)
      app.get '/ajax2?' do
        "hallo"
      end
    end
  end
  register MyExtension
end
```

and in **app.rb** all you should need is:

```
require './lib/my_extension.rb'
```

that's the first step, then move the contents of your extension into a gem and you can require the gem in your Gemfile in any sinatra application.

Comment: I updated my question - see the my_function(). I use only one file for sinatra code + one haml file. Then I have cron.rb file where I currently use mechanize to call my sintra code. I am sure I don't have to use mechanize but do everything 'locally'. How can I call my_function from cron.rb? I already call my_function from within sintra.rb.

Comment: Yessir.  It'll take some tinkering probably to get the module included correctly, but it's very useful skill, so it'll be worth the effort.